# object inject is not a member of package com.google

Tags: scala, playframework, single-page-application

I'm setting up a new server. The server starts but I get an error.

object inject is not a member of package com.google

I do not know what to do.
On the Internet, I saw a solution associated with the build.sbt file, but I do not know what to change there and how to change the controller itself.

My build.sbt

...

```
lazy val server = (project in file("server"))
.settings(
name := "server",
version := Settings.version,
scalaVersion := Settings.versions.scala,
scalacOptions ++= Settings.scalacOptions,
libraryDependencies ++= Settings.jvmDependencies.value,
commands += ReleaseCmd,
compile in Compile := ((compile in Compile) dependsOn 
scalaJSPipeline).value,
scalaJSProjects := clients,
pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(scalaJSPipeline),
pipelineStages := Seq(digest, gzip),
LessKeys.compress in Assets := true
)
.enablePlugins(PlayScala)
.disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin)
.aggregate(clients.map(projectToRef): _*)
.dependsOn(sharedJVM)

lazy val ReleaseCmd = Command.command("release") {
state => "set elideOptions in client := Seq(\"-Xelide-below\", 
\"WARNING\")" ::
"client/clean" ::
"client/test" ::
"server/clean" ::
"server/test" ::
"server/dist" ::
"set elideOptions in client := Seq()" ::
state
}
...
```

Application.scala

```
 ...
 package controllers

import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import boopickle.Default._
import com.google.inject.Inject 
import play.api.{Configuration, Environment}
import play.api.mvc._
import services.ApiService
import spatutorial.shared.Api


class Application @Inject() (implicit val config: Configuration, env: 
Environment) extends Controller {
val apiService = new ApiService()

def index = Action {
 Ok(views.html.index("lain"))
}
...
```

The error

```
 object inject is not a member of package com.google

 package controllers

 import java.nio.ByteBuffer
 import boopickle.Default._
 import com.google.inject.Inject 
 import play.api.{Configuration, Environment}
 import play.api.mvc._
 import services.ApiService
 import spatutorial.shared.Api
```

add   "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "28.0-jre"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC8fR.png)

Comment: Check if you've got guava added as a dependency anywhere in your `sbt.build`. It would be something similar to  `libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "28.0-jre"`.

Comment: Not. same error

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Try this import javax.inject._ instead of that import com.google.inject.Inject

Comment: thanks. I am try add mport javax.inject._.
Now error
You can add the Guice support module by adding "libraryDependencies += guice"

in my settings file 

  val jvmDependencies = Def.setting(Seq(
    "com.vmunier" %% "scalajs-scripts" % versions.scalajsScripts,
    "org.webjars" % "font-awesome" % "4.3.0-1" % Provided,
    "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % versions.bootstrap % Provided,
    "com.lihaoyi" %% "utest" % versions.uTest % Test
  )) 

How i can add guice ? 

val jvmDependencies = Def.setting(Seq(guice)) - ?